# Probability - expectation Puzzle: 1000 persons and a door

Tags: probability

You stand in an office by a door, with a measuring tape. Every time a person walks in you measure him or her and only keep tally of the “record” tallest. If the new person is taller than the preceding one, you count a record. If later another person is taller, you have another record, etc.

A 1000 persons pass through the door. How many records do you expect to have?

(Assume independence of height/arrival. Also note that the answer does not depend on any assumption about the probability distribution other than independence.)

PS - I'm able to come up with answer (~7.5) with a brute force approach. ( Running this scenario over 1000000 times and taking average ).  But here I'm looking for a theoretical approach.

Answer (score 0):

consider x_1 to x_1000 as the record, and max(i) as max of the sequence until i. The question is reduced to finding expected number of times the max(i) changes.

for i=0 to 999:

if x_i+1>max(i), then max(i) changes

Also, P(x_i+1>max(i))=1/i+1

answer=> summation of 1/1+i (i varies from 0 to 999) which is approx. 7.49